# Using Server Side (Spring WebSocket) without client code SockJS

Tags: javascript, java, spring-security, spring-websocket, stomp

I'm using Spring Boot MVC and Security. And now I want to use Spring WebSocket, for example, to create a chat. But could I write JS client code to server side?

When a user logs in to the site he has JSESSION, when he clicks the connect button he call connect () method of STOMP in order to subscribe and STOMP use JSESSION issued by server. Could I write this connection to server side of my application? Why use a repeated connection again in client side?

I want when user sends a message that the server understands what JS method was called and displays the container (HTML) of the message to all users who was subscribed to the topic.

Also, when the page is reloaded I use `windows.onload` to create connection again.

I want to use this code to server side T.T:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var stompClient = null;

      window.onload = function ( ) {
          connect();
      }

      function setConnected(connected) {
          document.getElementById('connect').disabled = connected;
          document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = !connected;
          document.getElementById('conversationDiv').style.visibility = connected ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
          document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = '';
      }

      function connect() {
          const socket = new SockJS('/hello');
          stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
          stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
              setConnected(true);
              console.log('Connected: ' + frame);

              stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (outmessage) {
                  const content   =  JSON.parse(outmessage.body).messageEntity.content;
                  const time      =  JSON.parse(outmessage.body).messageEntity.date_create;
                  const date      =  JSON.parse(outmessage.body).messageEntity.date;
                  const user_name =  JSON.parse(outmessage.body).userEntity.user_name;
                  const user_avat =  JSON.parse(outmessage.body).userEntity.user_avatar;

                   showGreeting(content, user_name, time, date, user_avat);
              });
          });
      }

      function disconnect() {
          stompClient.disconnect();
          setConnected(false);
          console.log("Disconnected");
      }

      function sendMessage() {
          const message = document.getElementById('text').value;
          stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'text': message }));
      }

      function showGreeting (message, user_name, date_time, date, avatar) {

          const ul      =   document.getElementById('ul-message');
          const li      =   document.createElement('li');
          const p_mes   =   document.createElement('p');
          const p_user  =   document.createElement('p');
          const p_time  =   document.createElement('p');

            const div_container = document.createElement('div');
            const img_chat_ava  = document.createElement('img');
            const div_chat_name = document.createElement('div');
            const div_chat_mess = document.createElement('div');
            const div_chat_time = document.createElement('div');

            img_chat_ava.src    = avatar;

            div_container.classList.add("message-container");
            div_chat_mess.classList.add("message");
            div_chat_time.classList.add("message-time");
            div_chat_name.classList.add("chat-name");
            img_chat_ava.classList.add("avatar");

            li.appendChild(div_container);

            div_container.appendChild(img_chat_ava);
            div_container.appendChild(div_chat_name);
            div_container.appendChild(div_chat_mess);
            div_container.appendChild(div_chat_time);

                 p_mes.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
                 p_mes.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
                 p_user.appendChild(document.createTextNode(user_name));
                 p_time.appendChild(document.createTextNode(date_time + " " + date));

            div_chat_mess.appendChild(p_mes);
            div_chat_name.appendChild(p_user);
            div_chat_time.appendChild(p_time);

            ul.appendChild(li);
      }

  </script>
```

Comment: Yes, you can use the Spring Boot WebSocket dependency to run your WebSocket-Server with STOMP. Here you find a guide written by the Spring Team to quick start: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Comment: @Oliver There is a sample where STOMP code on client side. But I want to use STOMP code on server side for users. I want that the server itself execute connect and subscribe methods for client who was authorized.

Comment: Double check the webpage article. It also covers the server side chapter named "Configure Spring for STOMP messaging".